# script for moving columns to rows

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel sheet that has 20 clients (listed in rows) each client has 193 columns.
The first 23 columns per row are my "constant". This is all the clients demographics. Then every 17 columns list details of their insurance. There may be an iteration of all 17 columns a maximum of 10 times. (170 columns, plus my 23 "constant columns", equals a total of 193 columns.)

I would like to basically separate each client per iteration of their 23 + 17columms. I should have a total of 40 columns. I should also have 10 Rows of the same member, the only thing that will change will be the last 17 columns.

I want my client details to go vertical in Rows vs horizontally in columns.
please help as it is very cumbersome to manually do this when I am working

Is there a VBA or a SQL or ACCESS way to do this?

Thank you,

Sabrina I

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are using Excel as a database - which Excel is not.

One suggestion solution would be to convert it into a database, e.g. an Access database.

Based on the scenario, you have outlined, the database would have a minimum of 2 tables:

- Client
- Insurance

From what you have described each Client can have one or more Insurance records. 
Therefore, the Client table has a one to many relationship with the Insurance table.

This is just a simplification of your scenario.

Converting your Excel spreadsheet to Access is not as simple as just clicking a button. You need to think about the design of your database and its referential integrity.

For starters, I suggest you read [this](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ie/excel-help/move-data-from-excel-to-access-HA010335712.aspx) article, it will help you understand the main concepts.